# Add ‘subscription_date’ and ‘user_ip_address’ fields for Newsletter Subscriber and show it in admin panel in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to add two custom fields for newsletter subscriber at which date customer subscribed and its ip address:
1) I had added two columns in ‘newsletter_subscriber’ table.
How this can be achieved?

In the file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php
I found the the functions like:

```
$this->setSubscriberEmail($email);
$this->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$this->setCustomerId(0);
```

But i did not found its code.
I think I also save data like that but how it will be possible ? where I have to define and declare code for the function like $this->seSubscriptionDate();

And how to display in Admin panel under Newsletter->Newsletter Subscriber ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had not find the solution or help from any person.
I bang my head and find the solution its very simple hope in future may some one’s time save by this post:
1)  Add columns in the table “newsletter_subscriber” say in my case “subscription_date” and “sub_ip_address”
2)  Add following two lines in the file @ two places
app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber.php

```
**$this->setSubscriptionDate(date("d-m-Y"));
**$this->setSubIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

One place: in the function:  public function subscribe($email)
Before: $this->save();
Second place: in the function:  public function subscribeCustomer($customer)
Before: $this->save();
Now data will be added in the table
Now to show in admin panel
1)  Open the file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Newsletter\Subscriber\Grid.php
Just add two required columns in it like

```
$this->addColumn('subscription_date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Subscription Date'),
            'index'     => 'subscription_date',
            'default'   =>    '----'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sub_ip_address', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('IP Address'),
            'index'     => 'sub_ip_address',
            'default'   =>    '----'
        ));
```

Now finish.
** This is the point where I spent my time and at the end I added this function on hit and trieal basis but it works.
Someone from Core magento team plz explain why this {setSubscriptionDate()}function work ? I had not declared anybody of this function. 
It seems it shows intellisense to detect table field?

Comment: any Set or Get does support searching for that field in the corresponding database

Comment: Yes its Magento ORM. its quite old post when i was baby in magento :) It made my day happy to read my silly question which I ask like I had not declared any body of this function hahaha. . . .

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem. However, in my case I am supposed to add a "country" and "gender" field in the newsletter form. So, on digging into the core for hours I figured this out. Below is the explaination:

In the **app/design/frontend//default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml**,
the form has getFormActionUrl() ?> in its action field. This referes to app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Block/Subscribe.php

The $this object used in the subscirbe.phtml file referes to this class (i.e. Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe) and thus **$this->getFormActionUrl()** in the subscribe.phtml file refers to the   function **getFormActionUrl()** of this class.

Now, this getFormActionUrl() is returning a method $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true)) which belongs to its parent Mage_Core_Block_Template (I mean the method getURL()). This part is not improtant to us.

See the parameter passed to the getURL() function which is **newsletter/subscriber/new**
The first part "newsletter" is the module name (app/code/code/Mage/newsletter), the second part "subscriber"  is the controller name (app/code/code/Mage/newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController) and the third part "new" is the method newAction in the controller SubscriberController.

Controller names are suffixed with **Controller** and function names are suffixed by **Action**. (Thanks to Phalcon framework to help understand this)

Now in the newAction()  method you can see that by default, only the email is being posted
as
    $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

What I did was, I cloned the subscribe.phtml template with a name custom-newsletter.phtml and add two fields with name "country" and "gender". Then added the following lines in the newAction():

```
        $country            = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('country');
        $gender             = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('gender');
```

Now at line number 67 of the SubscriberController (inside the newAction() method) there is a code :

```
$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
```

This line is calling the **subscribe** method of app/code/code/Mage/newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php and is passing the $email that is posted from newsletter form into it. I modified the line as:

$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email,$country,$gender);

Now, I have to edit the app/code/code/Mage/newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

When we talk about Models, we are talking about the database table the Model refers to. The model name is Subscriber and  it belongs to module Newsletter so, the database table that this model affects is **newsletter_subscriber**

**From this part on @Hassan Ali Sshahzad's question will be answered.**

I added two new columns there with the name: subscriber_country and subscriber_gender.
Now, Magento' system automatically makes available a getter and a setter function to these columns with the following name:

function getSubscriberCountry(){}
function setSubscriberCountry($country_name){}

So, all I had to do in the  model was:

1. Edit the method subscribe($email) to subscribe($email,$country,$gender)
2. add the following code in the subscribe($email,$country,$gender) function right before the try statement as follows:

   ```
   $this->setSubscriberCountry($country);
   $this->setSubscriberGender($gender);
   ```

try{
   $this->save()

---

Hassan's method played a key role in my understanding of the MVC of Magento so its a return from my side.